# Brute forcing an elliptic curve encrypted key

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, keys, cryptocurrency

I've been reading about ECC, and what I've established so far (correct me if I'm wrong) is that:

pubKey = privKey * G

where G is some special point on the secp256k1 curve.

Doesn't this mean we could attempt to brute force a private key by using:

privKey = pubKey/G

for all potential values of G.

I know it would require some unfeasible amount of attempts, but what if by chance that one of the first few attempts happened to have the correct value?

Answer (score 7):

> Doesn't this mean we could attempt to brute force a private key by using:
>   $$\mathit{privKey} = \mathit{pubKey}/G$$
>   for all potential values of $G$?

There seems to be a misunderstanding here: $\mathit{pubKey}$ and $G$ are fixed and publicly known, so there's nothing left to brute-force. The operation of "dividing" $\mathit{pubKey}$ by $G$ is (to the best of current public knowledge) computationally infeasible; this is the [elliptic-curve discrete logarithm problem (ECDLP)](http://wstein.org/edu/2007/spring/ent/ent-html/node89.html).
However, of course, one can brute-force by trying all possible values of $\mathit{privKey}$ and checking whether $\mathit{privKey}\cdot G=\mathit{pubKey}$ holds.

> what if by chance that one of the first few attempts happened to have the correct value?

This is very much related to [this recent question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/43955). The bottom line is: Yes, that could happen, but the probability is so incredibly low it is never going to occur *in practice*. (And in any case, if we're worried about someone just *guessing* our secret keys by pure luck, there's nothing anyone could do against it anyway.)

Comment: Going a step further, a lucky adversary could guess the _plaintext_ and they don't need the key _or_ ciphertext. In fact they could guess the message before you send it, before you encrypt it, before you _think_ of it, before you generate the key, and before you are born.

Answer (score -1):

1. primitive methods defined [here](https://asecuritysite.com/encryption/ecc3)
2. curve domain parameters available [here](https://javacardos.com/tools/elliptic-curve-domain-parameters)
3. check whether `public_key_xy = scalar_mult(private_key,curve.g)` matches expected target

Comment: Why do you not link official documents from http://secg.org ? What is your answer trying to address?